# Processor increasing by increasing RAM

Tags: memory

I have a computer with very low confg. The ram is DDR3 198MB and processor is 1.33ghz
IT takes a lot of time to open games and applications. Even MS word slows down. All games get stuck in the middle. I am planning to increase the ram thinking that it will solve the problem will it....?

If I increase the RAM (put in 4GB) will my computer speed up?

Comment: Please do not write in capitals... It is easier to read lower case and 'shouting' will not make the question clearer or answered sooner.

Comment: looking at your specs, its more likely DDR2 ot even ddr, not DDR3. I can't think of any systems with ddr3 with less than a gig of ram.

Comment: Without the rest of the system specs it is difficult to definitively say that it will help.  With that small an amount of RAM though it is quite likely that you will see a significant improvement by system responsiveness (but not flat out speed) by upgrading to 1GB or above.

Answer (score 1):

RAM is a strange thing, will it work; maybe!

The computer may be freezing for many reasons outside what you believe; I can write a process hungry application which doesn't require much RAM and since the computers RAM's 'threshold' is never reached, adding more RAM won't really make any difference. A new processor will though in this example.

Of course, each game is different and has different requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what OS are you using.

Anyway, yes, it will speed up your computer giving your applications consume more than 198MiB RAM. Because of extra consumption, memory is 'cached' in a swap file, which only adds extra I/O cycles to the HDD. By adding more RAM, less application memory will be loaded into the swap file, and more directly into your RAM, which will speed up your system.

* Note that some 32bit OSs will not let you see the whole 4 GiB RAM (Windows XP, for example, can only see aprox. 3 GiB). If you're not planning of covering more than 3GiB of RAM, for Windows at least, you will see even a greater bump in responsiveness if you disable the swap file/page file all together.

** Make sure your system support 4 GiB of RAM! Older systems may only work with 512 MiB DIMMs. Check your motherboard manual over the Internet, if you don't have a physical version of it.

Comment: Without knowing what operating system is being used ( although one can assume its Windows XP based on the specifications he did provide) you might want point out its not guarantee the system will be faster.  The processor is extremely slow, additional memory, won't the system faster.

Comment: I'm betting it's a dual core processor. No matter how old the dual core is, it's enough to run any Windows OK (I have a Pentium D and works well on Windows Vista). The slowest component is the one that gives the speed of the whole system, and in this case is the HDD. If all his programs run in swap, it's a major hit for the whole system

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @JourneymanGeek. Your specs are wrong (or maybe you got the "free" amount of RAM instead of the "total" amount?) You also haven't supplied enough information:
**1)** What processor is it? For example, an i5 1.3GHz is so many times faster than an Atom 1.3GHz that it's almost embarrassing. The model of the processor also makes a **huge** difference.
**2)** What kind of games are you trying to run? Card games happily run on pretty much any machine. On the other hand, getting something like Crysis 3 to run on a Celeron or an Atom isn't worth the effort.
**3)** What graphics card are you using? No amount of RAM in the world will fix slow games if you have a very weak graphics card.
**4)** Is it a desktop or a laptop? Laptop chips tend to be slower than their desktop counterparts, even when the model number is the same.
**5)** What operating system is this on? This matters for a very good reason: if it's Linux, and your running games through wine, then there might be massive speed loss with most games if you're unsure about what you're doing.

Without the above info it's difficult to give you an accurate answer, but the general rules are this:
RAM helps with loading speed, and for decreasing random in-game chopping. However, there is always fairly low theoretical maximum with how much it can assist with this. If you have too little RAM, then (unless your graphics card is very weak) you will notice a massive speed increase the +4GB, and much less random in-game chopping. If you already have enough RAM, then you probably won't notice any difference at all (so to answer your question, no it does not increase processing speed).

Answer (score -1):

More RAM will can boost the performance but provided that :

1. You play games that meets your minimum configuration of machine that includes CPU Frequency, CPU cores, RAM, Dedicated Graphics Card memory. I mean you cannot play Crysis 3 with just 4 GB of RAM right ? You must understand that.
2. Increasing RAM along with the paging file [Link for Paging file changes in XP and Vista](http://wiki.pcworld.com/index.php/Increasing_Page_File_Size_-_Windows_XP_and_Windows_Vista)
3. Multiprocessing is ok but doing low profile multi-application process is found extremely helpful.

PS : If you are looking for changing the entire configuration then just changing RAM wont work.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for a prompt reply and a -1, Nyways, I stand by my answer as it WILL definitely boost performance but I also mentioned three points that adds up in the reason why adding just RAM wont be enough.. I mentioned Crysis to prove a point that if he expects he wont be able to.. Hope it cleared your doubt.

Comment: @Pradip, no, it will not boost performance if the available RAM is already in excess... If my application is slow due to a processor and only ever requires 1MB of RAM, then adding 1GB of RAM will not help.

Comment: @DaveRook.. Right.. but did the question ever mentioned that there is in RAM excess ?

Comment: @Pradip The OP didn't mention it either way so we don't know, therefore a comment that it will `defintely` boost performance is incorrect.

Comment: @DaveRook.. apologies.. tell me this.. irrespective of what his configuration capabilities are.. how can even 1 GB RAM will not boost his performance considering he has just 198 MB RAM ? Give example if necessary.. RAM does boost performance but its not significant..but definite.. hence I think my comments are not incorrect.

Comment: @Ramhound Well the placement of word was wrong.. but just to prove point you cannot assume that 1.33 GHz machine will have max of 198MB of RAM. And please do not remove the downvote. I have changed definitely to can but still it will "definitely" improve performance.

Comment: @Pradip, but that was the only fault. I removed my -1 too. Do you understand the point though? An analogy is if you only need to carry 1 litre of water then a 1 litre bucket will suffice; having a 10 litre bucket will not provide any advantages because you will only fill 1 litre of water.

Comment: @DaveRook Thanks. No hard feelings though.